# I want to run the app in the background automatically every 1 minute ( I use TaskManager - Expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, taskmanager

I use expo app with android and I want to run my app in the background automatic, the task background should run the app every 1 minute, I use with **TaskManager - Expo**
I am new in expo react native and I need help with that issue because it's so hard for me.

What is missing from my code or what needs to be fixed there to make it work?

**My idea is just to run the app in the background automatically.**
also, let me know if I have to write something in the app.json (only if needs)

I call the "registerFetchTask" in app.js as well:

import { registerFetchTask } from './helpers/registerFetchTask'

registerFetchTask();

**and this is the code itself:**

```
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

const FETCH_TASKNAME = 'test_task'
const INTERVAL = 60

function test() {
    console.log('function is running')
}

export async function registerFetchTask() {
    TaskManager.defineTask(FETCH_TASKNAME, test);

    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    switch (status) {
        case BackgroundFetch.Status.Restricted:
        case BackgroundFetch.Status.Denied:
            console.log("Background execution is disabled");
            return;

        default: {
            console.debug("Background execution allowed");

            let tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
            if (tasks.find(f => f.taskName === FETCH_TASKNAME) == null) {
                console.log("Registering task");
                await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(FETCH_TASKNAME);

                tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
                console.debug("Registered tasks", tasks);
            } else {
                console.log(`Task ${FETCH_TASKNAME} already registered, skipping`);
            }

            console.log("Setting interval to", INTERVAL);
            await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(INTERVAL);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sadly `BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync` doesn't work on android https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/#backgroundfetchsetminimumintervalasyncminimuminterval

Comment: so you can tell me what to do ?
i just want to wake up my app in every 1 min on the background

Comment: To be honest i think it's not possible using expo, but I've never worked with BackgroundFetch and TaskManager, so maybe I'm wrong

Comment: and if i will make "expo eject" to my project ? it will help me ?

Comment: @halimi Did you find a solution?